# Shell Script: Is there a difference between "local foo" and "local foo="?

Tags: linux, shell, centos

I found following code in /etc/init.d/functions on CentOS.

```
status() {
    local base pid lock_file= pid_file=
    ...
```

4 variables are declared.
Two of them are not initialized, base and pid.
But rest of them are initialized with empty value, lock_file and pid_file.

I tested following code and found no differences.

```
local a b=

echo "a is $a, length is ${#a}"
echo "b is $b, length is ${#b}"
```

Is there any differences between them?

Comment: Local is for functions, right? What happens if you have a value for `foo` set external to the function? (I don't have a bash handy to test  with) . Good luck.

Comment: Like other languages, we can not refer external variables from "local declaration statement". So if you declare local variable with same name of external ones, it will be treated as other variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there *is* a difference. Consider the following function:

```
x() {
    local a b=

    echo ${a-X}
    echo ${b-X}
}
```

Calling this function in `bash-4.x` results in this output:

```
$ x
X

$
```

The `${parameter−word}` [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) expands to the expansion of `word` (in this case `X`) if the parameter is unset, or to the parameter value if it is set.

From the example output, it is obvious that `local a` leaves the variable `a` unset, while `local b=` explicitly sets it to the empty (null) string.

**EDIT:**

On the other hand, on `bash-3.x` you get this:

```
$ x


$
```

A call to `set` within the function verifies that `local a` in `bash-3.x` initializes that variable to the empty string. This, however, seems to have been a bug. From the `bash` changelog:

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.0-beta,
>   and the previous version, bash-4.0-alpha.
>
> ...
>
> e.  Fixed a bug that caused local variables to be created with the empty
>       string for a value rather than no value.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

But x function does not work for me, it shows 2 empty lines..
I checked bash(3.2.48) and zsh(4.3.11).

Is there something wrong with my environment?

Comment: Thank you very much! I could confirm this with bash-4.2.37.
I don't understand shell script well, so I'll learn it more!